# 15 psi at the house from a tank located 93 feet up

Tags: water, water-pressure, water-tank

I have a tank 93 feet above my house. There is about 350 feet of 2 inch hose from the tank to my house. I have a small creek filling the tank about 650 feet away from the tank. The flow into the tank is about 2-3 gallons a minute. The water line from the creek to the tank has a hill in the middle, but still fills the tank as the inlet is 50 feet above the tank.

Right now the 1000 gallon tank is full, the water pressure at the house from the 2inch hose going into 3/4 pex is only 15psi. Is there a potential that the line from the creek is holding up the water from the tank to the house?  Creating a vacuum that is holding the water back?

I have walked the installation, everything is buried 3 feet down, I do not see any water pooling or water creating a stream by escaping. If there was a break in the line, wouldn't the water be dirty or have sediment in it? It is crystal clear, no sediment.

What else could be holding up the water? Potential of air trapped in the pipe?  Would running the water through a garden hose encourage the air to leave the system?

Would a pump help or cause further damage?  I was thinking that a pump may cause the pipe to collapse even further.

If you need more clarity, please ask for it and not close the question.

Comment: If tank is full, then the problem is with the pipe from the tank to the house.  The water pressure should keep stuff from going into the pipe.  Water takes the easiest path to flow.  I think a lot of digging is in your future.

Comment: When you call technical support for a printer, for instance, the first thing they'll ask is if it's plugged in. Besides collapsed or burst line, have you checked all of the mechanical devices along the line's path? Valves, pressure regulators, filters, etc.?

Comment: Have you verified the tank vent is functioning, and checked pressure and flow at the tank outlet where the hose to house connects?

Comment: I have checked all the valves.  They are all open.  I attached a garden hose to the pex outlet that has been installed and let it run for awhile and it dropped the pressure by a pound.

Comment: I opened the lid on the tank and there was no sudden drop in water.  The tank doesn't have a vent.  Could this be the problem?  On a different forum I read that the tanks don't need vents.  Would a vent expose the tank to over flowing and casue freezing issues?

Comment: If there was a break in the line, I would see signs of leakage below the break would I not?  Would a rock or something being put on the pipe cause the restriction too?

Comment: On a different forum I read that the tanks don't need vents.  While talking to the tank supplier who also has a similar setup, said that the tank "breaths" so a vent isn't necessary.

Comment: @crip659, do you say "pipe" because of the low static pressure? (15psi) / (0.433psi/ft) = 35 ft would provide an elevation hint in that case, no? If there's a valve at the top, can you test the line's integrity by closing that valve and trying to drain the line?

Comment: What's going on with your tank's overflow?

Comment: Hi John, the reason your previous question was closed (from answering) was because it didn't have any details.  You didn't need to create a new question, you should have just edited it instead.  :-)

Comment: You mention `air trap`, which would be alleviated if you had a suitable vent.  I also think this needs a diagram.  A simple hand drawn one is fine.

Comment: Regarding the tanks overflow, if the tank is full the water just stays in the creek, and not enter the system at all.

Comment: regarding the air trap, wouldn't the air work it's way to the top of the tank?  I opened the valve to go through a garden hose and left it open for an hour and the pressure dropped a pound, now the pressure is back up to 15psi.  Is it possible that the pipe is kinked or constricted in some way?

Comment: @RohitGupta I had edited the last post and it wasn't being allowed to be answered after 10 hours.  I would like this fixed as I have a boiler installed that I cannot use as the PSI is too low

Comment: Have you tried opening the tank to the atmosphere to relieve any vacuum pressure that could be developing there (and running the house water with the tank still open)? If the tank is filled to the top, then you could be siphoning water from the creek. If your household-use flow rate is much higher than the normal flow rate to replenish the tank, then head loss in the creek-to-tank line could explain your low flow rate. The low static pressure doesn't support this theory in my mind, but I would try it anyway.

Comment: @popham I have opened the tank, however have not run the hose at the same time.  I will try tomorrow, it is too late tonight, I think this would possibly also alleviate any air traps that may be present

Comment: @John, I agree with the answer from your earlier question, really. The _static_ pressure should not be low. Top of my list is "malfunctioning or bumped pressure regulator" and "malfunctioning pressure gauge." This is a system that just started misbehaving? What was the normal static pressure (pressure reading when no water was running)?

Comment: There isn't a pressure regulator in the system till the boiler.  This is a new system so there isn't any history yet.  pressure gauge is a wet gauge and brand new with new pex connections.  The pressure gauge I installed is before the boiler in the inlet of water in the 3/4 pex

Comment: no water running pressure is 15psi according to the gauge I installed

Comment: And the pressure seems low when you open a faucet? You're getting a low flow rate? And there's nothing interesting at about 35 ft elevation above the gauge?

Comment: And how do you know that your tank is 93 ft above the gauge?

Comment: I used an app called my elevation, and the tank is at 2901 and the house is at 2808 feet.  I was thinking a different app would give better results.  as it is plus or minus 8 feet

Comment: I get a good flow rate into the house.  The toilet I just installed fills fast, the shower barely trickles, the garden hose looks like it is in the city and gets a good flow.

Comment: I filled a 5 gallon bucket in 42 seconds if this helps at all.

Comment: I missed an answer, at 35 feet above gauge or there abouts is a connector.  I wonder if it broke or became loose.  More reason to dig it out.

Comment: Hi John, you have an answer here and an answer on the previous one.  All these comments are saying that this question should be closed again.  Because answering it would be by opinions.

Comment: "If you need more clarity, please ask for it and not close the question." - the way Stack Exchange sites work is that you *improve* the existing question and it then gets reopened. Closing a question isn't (necessarily) permanent, and re-asking the same question is against the rules.

Comment: @JohnBlenkhorn That may well be your answer, the 35' above gauge connector.  Yes, the better thing is to edit your original question to add the detail.  If you feel like "I need to BUMP it to the top to get seen", that happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 350 ft of 2" PVC pipe, 20 ft of 3/4" PEX pipe (to the point where you measured the flow rate), and 35 ft of head (from your 15 psi), I compute a flow rate between 5.0 GPM and 5.1 GPM for your system. This is close enough to your 7.1 GPM that I believe that your pressure measurement is correct and that your elevation measurement was incorrect.

To compute the 5.0 GPM to 5.1 GPM theoretic flow rate, I used the Williams & Hazen formula from https://pvcpipesupplies.com/media/documents/engineering_design_data.pdf and I used a chart from https://mrpexsystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/17-Pressure-Drop-Charts.pdf.

To do the calculation, you hypothesize a flow rate, find the associated head losses from the cited sources, compute the orifice velocity using Bernoulli's equation (algebraically it reduces to v = sqrt(2gh) = sqrt(2(32.2ft/s^2)(35ft - head loss))), and multiply orifice velocity by the orifice's cross sectional area to get a flow rate. You iterate this process until the hypothesized flow rate agrees with the computed flow rate.

7.1 GPM is a nice flow rate. As long as you're in spec for stuff like your boiler, it shouldn't bother you.

Answer (score 0):

`"Is it possible that the pipe is kinked or constricted in some way?"`  Exactly, you are there, you need to check everything.  If there is a kink or sort of an s-bend, you will get an airlock.  This air will not rise into the tank.  That is why its called an airlock.  You need to find these spots and put a bleeding valve.  This will help in the future too.

A higher pressure pump may help, but it may burst the pipe as well.